# How can I get the weekly dates between start date and end date

Tags: php

I want to get weekly dates on the basis of the start date and end date.

Suppose my start date is **'2015-09-08'** and end date is **'2015-10-08'**.

On the basis of these dates I want the following result using PHP. I want the weekly dates between the start date and end date.

```
2015-09-15
2015-09-22
2015-09-29
2015-10-06
```

Comment: could you rephrase your question? give more clearly what is the actual output against required output and the code that is used to achieve what you are getting

Comment: @Blip: Please read the question again. I already mentioned the required output and the data which I have. Read it again.

Comment: You have stated a `startDate`, `endDate`. But is the output that you have posted are the output that your are getting or is it the expected output. if it is the output you are getting then where is the expected output. Lastly **where is the code that is required to get the output** that you are getting??

Comment: @Blip: The above mentioned output is not the output which I am getting. This is expected output which I want.

Comment: **WHERE IS YOUR CODE**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can take timestamps of both start date and end date and keep adding one weeks's timestamp to the current date until it is less than the end date timestamp.

something like below. check if this is what u asked for

```
$st=strtotime("2015-09-08");
$ed=strtotime("2015-10-08");
$wk=$st;
while($wk<$ed){

    $wk = strtotime('+1 Week',$wk);
    if($wk<$ed)
        echo date("Y-m-d",$wk);
    echo '<br>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where Column_name > '2015-09-08' 
and Column_name < '2009-10-08'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_name 
WHERE Column_name BETWEEN ‘2015-09-08’ AND ‘2015-10-08’
```

Comment: Please let me know how did you understood that the problem pertains to `selet` statement

Comment: it looks like the OP just wants to track Sunday or one day of the week anyway, rather than all of them

Answer (score 0):

As you want weekly dates using php. The following code will do for you

```
<?php
$startdate='2015-09-08';
$enddate='2015-10-08';
$date=$startdate;
while($date<=$enddate)
{
$date = strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($date));
$date=date("Y-m-d", $date);
if($date<=$enddate)
echo $date."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Php s strtotime function might come is handy here. You could try this:

```
  $start =  '2015-09-08';
  $end = // you end date as string
   $offset = strtotime($start);
   $limit = strtotime($end);

    for($t = $offset; $t < $limit; $t += 86400 * 7){
     echo date('Y m d') ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27966/Select-dates-of-a-day-between-two-dates) has code to do exactly what you want, you can get the date of every Sunday or Monday or whatever day you choose between two dates

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$startdate= strtotime("15-09-08");
//$startdate= strtotime("08 September 2015");
$enddate= strtotime("15-10-08");
//$enddate= strtotime("08 October 2015");

$jump_date= $startdate;

if($enddate>$startdate)
while($jump_date< $enddate)
{
    $jump_date= strtotime("+1 week", $jump_date);
    if($jump_date< $enddate)
        echo date('Y-m-d', $jump_date).'<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the built in php function `strtotime` to add a period of 1week

```
$ds='2015-09-08';
$df='2015-10-08';

$ts=strtotime( $ds );
$tf=strtotime( $df );

while( $ts <= $tf ){
    $ts = strtotime('+1 week', $ts );
    echo date( 'Y-m-d', $ts ).'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
  // Set timezone
  //date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

  // Start date
  $date = '2015-09-08';
  // End date
  $end_date = '2015-10-08';

  while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) { 
   echo $date."<br/>";
   $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($date))); 
 }
```

?>